# Get foreground mask from numpy array

Tags: python, image-processing, foreground

My goal is create a foreground mask from a numpy array which have float point numbers as elements. Every mtrix have been processed through SVD and most background have be removed. The value ranges from -146 to 171 and the pyplot.imshow function can show the image. However openCV cannot accept the numpy array as input. I have searched and tried many function to transform array from image in PIL and OpenCV, but all failed.

```
>> import numpy as np
>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>> import cv2
>> people_frames.shape
   (120, 160, 1499)
>> people_frames.dtype
   dtype('float64')
>> test=people_frames[:,:,473]
>> np.amax(test),np.amin(test)
   (171.04012891092754, -146.60759656055131)
>> plt.imshow(test,cmap='gray')
```

The above interactive result goes well and test is indeed a numpy array.
The following code gives error message:

```
mask = np.zeros(test.shape,np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

rect = (0,0,119,159)
cv2.grabCut(test,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1)
```

the error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-1ca3406e3367> in <module>()
      5 
      6 rect = (0,0,119,159)
----> 7 cv2.grabCut(test,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
      8 mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1)

error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\grabcut.cpp:543: error: (-5) image must have CV_8UC3 type in function cv::grabCut
```

I am not sure the grabCut works on grey scale image or not. So I tried adaptive threshold in OpenCV but it still cannot accept test as a argument.

```
cv.adaptiveThreshold(test,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
```

but I still get error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-bc6d6ef4108c> in <module>()
----> 1 cv2.adaptiveThreshold(test,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1520: error: (-215) src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function cv::adaptiveThreshold
```

I have really no idea how to get the foreground mask. I am not stick to the openCV module but it seems to be most helpful .Any other methods are welcomed.

Comment: By "processed through SVD" are you performing some sort of dimensionality reduction to the image?  GrabCut operates on actual RGB pixels, so submitting a dimensionality reduced image prior to reconstruction would not work.  Can you tell us why you are using the SVD before GrabCut?  That would actually help.

Comment: @rayryeng  Thank you. I use the same way in https://preview.tinyurl.com/yadymabk to remove background. I use SVD to get low rank matrix and subtract the low-rank matrix from orginal image, which have been turned to a numpy matrix. I use PIL to load and convert original series of images as grey scale and use np.array turn them to numpy arrays.